# Use spinner in external class because needed in all other activities

Tags: java, android, class, spinner, external

My question is how can i put my spinner in an external java class and implement it in all other activities (works as a menu), here is my spinner code:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.comboCasino);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.comboCasino, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(0, false);
        // this will be called when you select any item in this spinner
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // get the text at that position
                switch(position) {
                case 0: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartingPoint.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break; }
                case 1: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Simmering.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost); 
                    break; }
                case 2: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LugnerCity.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break; }
                case 3: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Gmunden.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break;}
                case 4: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Salzburg.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break; }
                case 5: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Linz.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break; }
                case 6: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Saalbach.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break; }
                case 7: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Innsbruck.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost); 
                    break;}
                case 8: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Reutte.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break; }
                case 9: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Bregenz.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost); 
                    break; }
                case 10: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Kufstein.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break; }
                case 11: {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Bratislava.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                    break; }
                }       
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            }
        });
```

it shoud be saved for example in menu.java and should be called in every activity, how do i do that correctly? thank you in advance.

Comment: Create a BaseActivity class that extends a Activity class and add the spinner code inside that.Now whenever you need to use a spinner in other class,extend that class to BaseActivity and call the function from BaseActivity to create spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your own Spinner class:

```
public class MenuSpinner extends Spinner {

   public MenuSpinner(Context context) {
      super(context);
      ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.comboCasino, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      setAdapter(adapter);
      setSelection(0, false);   
      .
      .
      .
   }
}
```

And then add it in your layout

```
<com.yourpackage.MenuSpinner
   android:id="comboCasino"
   .
   .
   . />
```

If you want more detailled information visit http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: for the Spinner class, should i create a new Java class or an Android Activity?

Comment: A simple Java class which extends android.widget.Spinner

Comment: isnt there any possibility i could create a template or something for all other activities?

Comment: what do you mean with template?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same menu in all your activities, the best way to do this is by creating a superclass that extends Activity and let all your other activities extend this activity.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity { // menu code  }

public class StartingPoint extends BaseActivity { //... }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a constructor for menu.java

   ```
         menu(Context mcontext){
             this.mcontext = mcontext;
           }
   ```
2. Now in place of getApplicationContext() call it by passing of object of class where you want to use Spinner property.

   ```
          Menu object = new Menu(object_of_current_class);
           object.ShowSpinner();
   ```